# How to add event handlers to dynamic control in asp.net to do postback? Other than using Javascript, is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

How to add event handlers to dynamic control( a button) in asp.net to do postback? Other than using Javascript, is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible.

So, for example, in your `Page_Load` you can create the button.

This example is using VB

This has to be recreated on postback, so DO NOT wrap it in an `If (Not isPostBack)` - otherwise it will not work

```vb
Dim btn As Button = New Button() With {.Text = "Click Me", .ID = "MyId"}
AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf MyBtnClick ' This is the method to call
```

and then you handle the click in here:

```vb
Private Sub MyBtnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button) ' Gets the button that fired the method
    ' Do your code here
End Sub
```

And here is the same in C#

```
Button btn = new Button {Text = "Click Me",ID = "MyId"};
btn.Click += new EventHanlder(MyBtnClick);
```

And Method being called

```
private void MyBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender; // Gets the button that fired the method
    // Do your code here
}
```

Comment: You're welcome Same. If this helped you, please mark this as the answer. Marking a question answered helps other people when they are looking for the same problem. Also helps you in the future too as people will be more inclined to help when you take the time to mark as answered :)

Comment: Yeah sure... will care to do that, and it's my responsibility too. I'm awaiting my friends response who's actually working on an asp.net project. So he'll have to get back to me :) Thanks alot! :) Regards

Comment: Is there a difference between doing it this way and having the sub `Handles btn.Click`? For instance if the button was not defined programmatically, but was rather defined in asp or some other markup?

Comment: Nope. No different. Just 2 ways of assigning the same handler.

Comment: in C# it is incorrect to say btn.Click += MyBtnClick.  You would need to create a handler from that delegate, so ...  btn.Click += new EventHanlder(MyBtnClick).

Comment: @AgapwIesu - thanks, I've updated it. I think, back then, I was doing a fair bit of VB, so forgot the c# syntax :)

Comment: I want to dynamically generate button controls on postback and I've found this solution doesn't work for me. I tried to create a new eventhandler on every page_load and then assign this to btn.click when I create it, but I just can't get my event method to be called. Am I right in thinking I've hit a limitation here and I need to use javascript/jquery?