# With ASP.NET, how can I change what a dynamically-generated button does when pressed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Right now I'm generating a bunch of information pulled from an API and storing it into strings, and displaying that info into cells in a table. I'd like to have a button on each row that, if the user presses it, will grab the information specific to that row. The goal is to be able to click a button and have that information transferred to another list/table of 'selected' items.

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET in general, and I'm aware of how button 'onclick' methods work when you've manually added the button to a web page yourself, but not how to go about doing so when they're generated through code.

Comment: add event handler dynamically along with control; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690784/how-to-add-event-handlers-to-dynamic-control-in-asp-net-to-do-postback-other-th

Comment: Right, but how would I go about selecting the information on the specific row that the button is on when it's pressed? I understand the idea of the button click event, but not how to get information specific to the row that the button is on.

Comment: use CommandArgument to pass unique identifier of that row; in button click event (shared for all buttons); retrieve CommandArgument and based on this value, other row properties; if you use GridView, there are plenty of articles out there

Answer (score 0):

If you create an event handler in your code behind for the button, you can then wire each button up to that event handler. Using the parameters of the handler, you know which button was handled.

```
public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    button.DoSomething();
}
```

And each of your buttons would be attached to the event.

```
<asp:Button OnClick="Button_Clicked" />
```